# Trigger not working on Form Submit in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, form-submit

I have written the below code.  Trigger is activated upon form submit.  Authorization done. but still, email doesn't get triggered.  all variables are fetched from spreadsheet.  Raised ticket with Issue tracker and they have closed the ticket with below remarks.

"
Thank you for filing this issue.

Your screenshot suggests that there is no error in the execution of your trigger.
I can also confirm that you are using the method `MailApp.sendEmail` correctly. However, I do not know where your variable `onboard` comes from, how it gets populated  "onFormSubmit" and how your array "onboard.values[]" is created and populated.

I can only assume this is where your error comes from. Please be aware that your problem is not a bug from Google's side,  but a developer issue. For assistance with developer issues, please use the developer platform www.stackoverflow.com

Thank you for your understanding!
05:27PM
Status: Assigned  Won't Fix (Not Reproducible)
"

```
function myFunction(onboard) {

  var conId = onboard.values[1];
  var conName = onboard.values[2];
  var conNo = onboard.values[3];
  var conEmail = onboard.values[4];
  var conAddress = onboard.values[5];
  var conCity = onboard.values[6];
  var conDob = onboard.values[7];
  var conAcc = onboard.values[8];
  var conBank = onboard.values[9];
  var conIfsc = onboard.values[10];
  var conType = onboard.values[11];
  var payScheme = onboard.values[12];

  var subject = 'Welcome Onboard as Master-Brains Connector | '+conName;

  var htmlBody = 'Greetings from Master-Brains!!!<br><br>We are pleased to update you that we have successfully confirmed you as Master-Brains authorized Connector';

  MailApp.sendEmail(conEmail, subject, htmlBody, {'htmlBody':htmlBody, cc: 'raajesh@master-brains.com'})

}
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to  SO. Have you check all you variables?

Comment: Hello Raajesh! What is your issue exactly? Are you receiving the e-mail on the address specified as "cc"? Please make sure to check in the SPAM folder too. Cheers!

Comment: Dear All, Would like to inform you that I observed the emails are working only within master-brains domain. I changed 'To' and 'Cc' as my email address, raajesh@master-brains.com and the emails are working. I am worried why it is not working for gmail and other domain accounts. Would appreciate if someone help me on this.

Comment: Hello @RaajeshS! Do you have any IPs whitelisted in your **Admin Console** settings? Would you mind checking? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use hardcoded values in variables, just to be sure that function triggering works and E-mail can be sent and received.

If it is working with hardcoded values you should post some information about how do you create onboard associative array.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response!!!  I have created a google form, which has some fields for filling.  Upon submitting the form, the email has to be triggered.  Thats the requirement.  I have created form.  Basis response sheet, I have written the codes in script editor.  Field No.5 in response sheet has the email to which trigger needs to be sent, hence, I have named "Onboard" as the name of the function and assigned all values from the response sheet.  Then, trigger is enabled.

Comment: Dear All, Would like to inform you that I observed the emails are working only within master-brains domain.  I changed 'To' and 'Cc' as my email address, raajesh@master-brains.com and the emails are working.  I am worried why it is not working for gmail and other domain accounts.  Would appreciate if someone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

- Check your SENT folder.  Sometimes emails are sent, but never arrive.
- Emails can also be blocked for various reasons.
- If you send exact duplicate emails as tests, subsequent emails may
  never be shown in the receiving account.  I guess Google may check
  for exact duplicates, and not show subsequent exact emails.  When testing,
  don't always send exact duplicate emails.
- There have been issues when being signed into multiple Google
  accounts at the same time.  Were you ever signed into two or more
  Google accounts at the same time when creating the Form submit
  trigger?

Comment: Thank you for the response, however, both the points are not applicable with me...  I tried with multiple emails for testing, it didn't work.  I signed in only in one google account.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I'm interested in this situation.  If you get more information or find the problem, please let us know.